# Python mover arquivos para sub-pastas de nome único

Tags: python

boa noite!

a nível de estudo, estou tentando criar um script com a regra abaixo:

o que eu estou tentando fazer é:

> -dentro da pasta 'origem' terão dezenas de arquivos.
>
> -eu preciso que o python mova os arquivos que começem com 'A', de 8 em 8 arquivos para uma sub-pasta de nome único dentro do destino.
>
> -ou seja, pegue 8 arquivos e coloque em uma sub-pasta única, depois pegue mais 8 e coloque em outra sub-pasta, assim por diante,
>
> -quando a pasta origem tiver uma quantidade abaixo de 8, o processo é terminado.

estou há 2 dias tentando fazer conforme o código abaixo.

acredito que esteja errando em algo simples, mas não consigo identificar.

fico grato caso alguém possa me ajudar.

obrigado!

```
import shutil, os, datetime

# para criar uma pasta de nome único, usei datetime.now
data = datetime.datetime.now()
folder_dist = data.strftime("%d""%H""%M""%S")

# pasta origem
origem = r'D:\origem'

# pasta destino
destino = r'D:\destino' + '\\' + folder_dist  # cria uma pasta de nome único

# muda para a pasta origem
os.chdir(origem)

# cria uma lista dos arquivos dentro da pasta origem
files = os.listdir(origem)

# cria uma lista filtrando os arquivos que começam com 'A'
files_a = [f for f in files if f.startswith('A')]

# quantidade de arquivos que quero mover da pasta origem
files_move = 8

# neste ponto preciso que o python mova de 8 em 8 arquivos para dentro de uma pasta única dentro do destino.
# se não houver ao menos 8 arquivos na pasta, o python termina o processo.
while len(files_a) >= 8:
    for file in files_a:
        os.makedirs(destino, exist_ok=True)
        shutil.move(file, destino)
        files_move -= 1
        if files_move == 0:  # sair do loop
            break
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando? bom você falar isso pra facilitar a vida de quem tentar ajudar.

Comment: oi erick, bom dia, sim me desculpe :)
o erro é o seguinte:
o script faz a primeira separacao, tudo certo, quando vai fazer a segunda separacao...dá um erro falando q arquivo já existe.

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns problemas com seu código:

- você cria a variável `files_a`, uma lista de strings, uma única vez. Como o tamanho da lista nunca muda durante seu código, a condição `while len(files_a) >= 8:` vai ser ou sempre falsa (seu loop nunca executa) ou sempre verdadeira (seu loop nunca acaba). Note que o fato de você mover arquivos com `shutil.move(file, ...` não faz com que o string `file` saia automaticamente de dentro da lista.
- de maneira similar, você cria a pasta `destino` uma única vez, fora do loop. Isso significa que `shutil.move(..., destino)` sempre irá colocar os arquivos nessa mesma pasta. Isso não vai causar um erro como a primeira observação, mas é um comportamento diferente do que você descreveu.

Para corrigir o primeiro ponto, considere passar os nomes de arquivos para `shutil.move` usando o método `pop` de listas, que "extrai" um elemento da lista a cada chamada.

Para o segundo ponto, basta construir a variável `destino` dentro do loop, da mesma forma como você já faz agora.

A seguir um exemplo que faz o que você quer:

```
import shutil, os, datetime

# pasta origem
origem = r'D:\origem'
# muda para a pasta origem
os.chdir(origem)
# cria uma lista dos arquivos dentro da pasta origem
files = os.listdir(origem)
# cria uma lista filtrando os arquivos que começam com 'A'
files_a = [f for f in files if f.startswith('A')]
# quantidade de arquivos que quero mover da pasta origem
files_move = 8

# a cada iteração, checa se há o número mínimo 
#  de arquivos começando por 'A' na pasta origem
while len(files_a) >= files_move:
    # nome único para pasta destino dos próximos arquivos
    data = datetime.datetime.now()
    folder_dist = data.strftime("%d""%H""%M""%S")
    destino = r'D:\destino' + '\\' + folder_dist
    # cria a pasta de destino
    os.makedirs(destino, exist_ok=True)
    # move N arquivos (N = variável files_move), 
    # removendo os nomes de dentro da lista files_a
    for _ in range(files_move): 
        file = files_a.pop() 
        shutil.move(file, destino)
```

Comment: boa tarde jfaccioni!
você é o cara, sabe muito!!
só um detalhe que não funcionou, ele move todos os arquivos para a pasta nova...
oq eu gostaria é que fosse movido apenas 8 por vez..
move 8 e cria uma sub-pasta...move mais 8 para outra sub-pasta...assim por diante.
vou estudar teu código.
muito brigado!

Comment: Oi @hanspereira, pelo visto não entendi sua pergunta inicial corretamente. Você quer mover 8 arquivos a cada execução do programa (roda uma vez, move 8, roda mais uma vez, move mais 8, ...)? Se for isso, acredito que trocando o `while` por um `if` deva funcionar.

Comment: oi @jfaccioni, obrigado cara!
consegui fazer funcionar, não sei se usei a forma correta ou se fiz gambiara :)...
mas funcionou, a única alteração que eu fiz no teu código foi acrescentar "%f" dentro do data.strftime...ficou assim: data.strftime("%d""%H""%M""%S""%f")...acrescentando o milisegundos funciona perfeitamente...acredito q antes, sem o milisegundos, já que o python faz tudo muito rápido...acontecia de entrar mais arquivos pq o processo era tão rápido que sobreescrevia.

Comment: Ah entendi, faz sentido sim a sua alteração, e não havia me dado conta que isso poderia ser um problema heheh!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa "montar" um nome de diretório diferente para cada grupo de arquivos que você deseja copiar. Usar a data e hora como nome único de diretório pode fazer com que todos os arquivos sejam copiados para o mesmo destino no mesmo segundo.

Segue uma solução comentada para o seu problema com um *approach* similar ao seu:

```
import shutil
import os

qtd = 8         # Quantidade de arquivos no bloco
origem = '/tmp' # Diretorio de origem

# Recupera lista de todos os arquivos iniciados
# por 'A' Contidos no diretorio de origem
arquivos = [f for f in os.listdir(origem) if f.startswith('A')]

# Divide lista de arquivos em sublistas (blocos)
# com o tamanho definido
blocos = [arquivos[i: i + qtd] for i in range(0, len(arquivos), qtd)]

# Para cada bloco de arquivos...
for i, bloco in enumerate(blocos, 1):

    # Monta caminho de destino dos arquivos contidos no bloco
    destino = os.path.join(origem, 'Destino' + str(i).zfill(4))

    # Cria diretorio de destino se ele nao existir
    os.makedirs(destino, exist_ok=True)

    # Para cada arqivo no bloco...
    for arquivo in bloco:

        # Exibe mensagem de status
        print(f"Movendo arquivo: {arquivo}' => '{destino}'")

        # Move o arquivo para o destino
        shutil.move(arquivo, destino)
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lacobus, vou colocar teu código em prática, valeu!